# How to install Google Play services on an Android 7.0 emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, google-play-services, 7.0-nougat

I have the stable version of Android N Preview SDK released last month. The emulators are working perfectly but there is no Gapps available for Android N and there is no way I have found to install Google Play Services in the Android N emulators.

Can someone please assist me with installing Google Play Services and/or Gapps on an Android N emulator?

Comment: Did you ever get Google Play Services working on a 7.0 emulator? I can get it to work on 7.1.1, but the same method does not work on 7.0.

Comment: @gavsiu not yet

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [OpenGApps](http://opengapps.org/) and [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads), but there's probably a better solution.